# Do roll up summary calculations count against the CPU limit?

Tags: apex, governorlimits, master-detail, roll-up-summary, cpulimit

Hopefully a straightforward question - if I insert/update/delete records into an object that is a detail of another object, does the server performing the roll up summaries count against the platform CPU limit?

Comment: There is an official statement  "*Calculating roll-up summary field values can take up to 30 minutes, depending on the number of records affected and other factors*.". Do you think it count against CPU Limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Rollup summary is part of Database DML.

At official salesforce manual, there are next lines:

> CPU time is calculated for all executions on the Salesforce
>   application servers occurring in one Apex transaction. CPU time is
>   calculated for the executing Apex code, and for any processes that are
>   called from this code, such as package code and workflows. CPU time is
>   private for a transaction and is isolated from other transactions.
>   Operations that don’t consume application server CPU time aren’t
>   counted toward CPU time. For example, the portion of execution time
>   spent in the database for DML, SOQL, and SOSL isn’t counted, nor is
>   waiting time for Apex callouts.

But in order of trigger execution, next lines are mentioned:

> 16. If the record contains a roll-up summary field or is part of a cross-object workflow, performs calculations and updates the roll-up summary field in the parent record. Parent record goes through save procedure.

So, that mean if child record is updated with changes to fields, on which rollup summary is based on parent object, parent one would be updated as well, and it would cause trigger fire on parent record, that may hit limit.

How to test -- create simple rollup on amount on opportunity/account pair, add trigger with infinite loop on account, update amount on opportunity. Update statement would fail because of CPU limit.

Links:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm